# How to return top 30 customer revenue combines from service and sales table

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I can pull the individual rows with this query but want to combine the two tables and show, by customer No,  the top 30 customer by salesperson.

```
select top 30   sil.[Sell-to Customer No_]as 'Customer No.',
                cus.[Name], 
                sil.[Responsibility Center], 
                sil.[Amount] as 'Total',
                'SALES'
FROM            [Sales Invoice Line] sil left outer join [Customer]cus
on              sil.[Sell-to Customer No_] = cus.[No_]  
where           sil.[Amount] > 0
and             sil.[Responsibility Center] != 'cis'
and             sil.[Posting Date] between '10-01-13' and (current_timestamp)

group by        sil.[Amount], sil.[Sell-to Customer No_], sil.[Responsibility Center], cus.[Name]


union all


select top 30   sil.[Customer No_],
                cus.[Name], 
                sil.[Responsibility Center], 
                sil.[Amount] as 'Total', 
                'SERVICE'
FROM            [Service Invoice Line] sil left outer join [Customer]cus
on              sil.[Customer No_] = cus.[No_]
where           sil.[Amount] > 0
and             sil.[Responsibility Center] != 'cis'
and             sil.[Posting Date] between '10-01-13' and (current_timestamp)

group by        sil.[Amount], sil.[Customer No_], sil.[Responsibility Center], cus.[Name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your entire query that returns 60 rows with a query to get the top 30.

```
select top 30 x, y, z 
from (
    select top 30 x, y, z from a where blah
    union all
    select top 30 x, y, z from b where blah
) x --here's the alias for the subquery
order by topcriteria
```

The order by is important so you get the proper "top" of the query.

Edit: Here's your sum example:

```
select top 30   sil.[Sell-to Customer No_]as 'Customer No.',
                cus.[Name], 
                sil.[Responsibility Center], 
                sum(sil.[Amount]) as 'Total',
                'SALES'
FROM            [Sales Invoice Line] sil left outer join [Customer]cus
on              sil.[Sell-to Customer No_] = cus.[No_]  
where           sil.[Amount] > 0
and             sil.[Responsibility Center] != 'cis'
and             sil.[Posting Date] between '10-01-13' and (current_timestamp)
group by        sil.[Sell-to Customer No_], sil.[Responsibility Center], cus.[Name]
```

Comment: So I should include my joins in the subquery, correct?

Comment: Yes... if your queries are returning the 60 rows you're looking for, just wrap them as they are. I just shortened my example for brevity. :)

Comment: Im getting a syntax error on my last ')' line prior to my order by...Hmmm.

Comment: You need to alias the subquery. I forgot that part. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Ok.  This is giving me highest to lowest amount for each customer but not the total for each customer, highest to lowest.

Comment: In other words, it is listing the same customer several times highest to lowest...

Comment: Then you need to sum the amount, and group by the customer. If you group by amount and don't sum, you just get individual records.

Comment: That nailed it.  Thank you.